# Как применить анимацию к блоку при скроллинге ниже определенной точки?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проблема с анимацией.

Планируется, что меню `navBar` при скроллинге ниже `header` будет плавно менять прозрачность и становиться `fixed`, а при возвращении назад всё так же плавно убирается.

На деле происходит единственная анимация. Появление анимируется как надо, а вот остальные анимации происходят как если бы не было вызова `.animate()`.
Подскажите, как сделать действие обратное появлению и почему анимация происходит только первый раз?

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    if(($(window).scrollTop()>$navBarHeight)&&($(window).scrollTop()<$headerHeight+17)){
        $(".navBar").css({"opacity":"0"});  
    }else if($(window).scrollTop()<$navBarHeight){
        $(".navBar").css({"opacity":"1"});  
    }


    if (($(window).scrollTop()>$headerHeight)){
        $(".navBar").animate({
        opacity:1
        },1500);
        $("header").css({"margin-top":$(".navBar").height()});
        $(".navBar").addClass("stick");

    }else {
        $(".navBar").removeClass("stick");
        $("header").css({"margin-top":0});
    }   
});
```

Comment: где $headerHeight и причие переменные, да и целиком бы всё -- жмите кнопку <> и пишите код целиком

Comment: так тут только один вызов animate - почему анимаций должно быть несколько?

Comment: @Grundy я считал , что этот animate будет работать каждый раз как первый раз(если можно так выразиться), то есть каждый раз когда я прокручиваю до момента, где он должен вызваться он вызывается, а происходит игнорирование этой анимации вообще во всех случаях , кроме первого.

Comment: можете создать пример который воспроизводит вашу проблему? на jsfiddle либо тут в snippets?

Comment: @Grundy Если я правильно сделал всё , то вот ссылка https://jsfiddle.net/0usrLh11/. Прокрутите до появления меню после Header, потом назад пока оно не исчезнет и опять вниз. Вот на второй раз меню уже выскакивает мгновенно без какой-либо анимации

Comment: @D.Che, да, почему-то `opacity` - при скрытии не меняется, соответственно когда потом вызывается animate - значение уже `1` и считается что анимация кончилась уже

Comment: хотя она и в коде не устанавливается в `0`

Comment: @Grundy, да вроде opacity должно опять становиться 0 , когда мы находимся в области хедера, самая первая часть кода.

Comment: @D.Che, нет, смотри разметку, оно там всегда `1` остается, а исчезает он только за счет того что маргин меняется и он вверх улетает

Comment: @Grundy , Действительно , opacity равно единице во время хедера , а почему он не меняется , если есть код , который это должен делать? Код не срабатывает или что?

Comment: скорее срабатывает код которые ее в единицу выставляет, и все, так как на 0 он не сбрасывается нигде таки остается. а не сбрасывается возможно из-за анимате. А почему вместо него просто css тоже самое не сделать?

Comment: @Grundy, Сделать класс с opacity и через addClass() добавить в нужный момент? Если так , то я думал сделать , но не хватило мозгов, куда transition вставить , либо я уже пытался , но тоже не получилось , поэтому решил делать так.

Comment: а что должно происходить в первом `if`? он вообще нужен?

Comment: @Grundy , первый if , как раз и устанавливает opacity в ноль, если мы находимся между навигацией и концом хедера, иначе, если мы выше хедера, то устанавливаем в единицу

Comment: да, проблема в `if`

Comment: @Grundy , а в чем именно? вроде все логично и не должно быть такого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы исключить выставления свойства `opacity` в стиле у конкретного элемента, лучше использовать css-классы вместо js функций.

В данном случае можно просто добавить класс, например

```
.inv {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

который надо использовать, когда нужно скрыть элемент

и добавить в класс, например `stick`, `transition` для свойства `opacity`

```
transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
```

Пример

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $headerHeight = $("header").height();
  $navBarHeight = $(".navBar").height();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $navBarHeight = $(".navBar").height();
    $headerHeight = $("header").height();
  });


  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if (($(window).scrollTop() > $navBarHeight) && ($(window).scrollTop() < $headerHeight + 17)) {
      $(".navBar").addClass('inv');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < $navBarHeight) {
      $(".navBar").removeClass('inv');
    }


    if (($(window).scrollTop() > $headerHeight)) {
      $("header").css({
        "margin-top": $(".navBar").height()
      });
      $(".navBar").addClass("stick");

    } else {
      $(".navBar").removeClass("stick", 1000);
      $("header").css({
        "margin-top": 0
      });
    }

  });
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 400px;
}
body {
  font-family: "RobotoRegular";
}
a,
a:active,
a:link,
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #679FD2;
}
nav {
  background-color: black;
}
nav .current,
nav a:hover {
  color: #BF8430;
  border-left: 1px solid #BF8430;
  border-right: 1px solid #BF8430;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
nav a:not(:hover) {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
nav ul {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.inv {
  opacity: 0;
}
.stick {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: opacity 1.5s ease;
}
header {
  background-color: #FF4540;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
header .logoBlock {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header #firstWords {
  font-family: "AdineKirnbergRegular", Times, sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
}
header #secondWords {
  font-family: "AdineKirnbergRegular", Times, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
header .face {
  border-radius: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.something {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navBar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
          <li><a href="#start">Начало</a>
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
          <li><a href="#about">Обо мне</a>
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
          <li><a href="#abilities">Способности</a>
          </li>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
          <li><a href="#gallery">Галерея</a>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<header>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem id voluptate nulla incidunt voluptas quo nesciunt, explicabo, qui aut dolorum esse commodi inventore veritatis hic modi nam dolorem placeat sit!
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel earum consectetur minus, aliquam nostrum odio molestias odit officia, fugit tempora amet perspiciatis nemo dicta repellat magni quisquam vitae nobis quidem.</div>
  <div>Magnam quae, laboriosam dignissimos eligendi! Atque exercitationem harum aperiam provident non illum tempore eos incidunt obcaecati, ut adipisci explicabo blanditiis iste ducimus dolore fuga magni odit cupiditate voluptatibus quis facere!</div>
  <div>Inventore sapiente omnis autem id ullam, cumque accusantium, nemo doloremque enim voluptas iste vitae. Eligendi delectus ipsam voluptate! Libero quam itaque eum nobis quia numquam corporis, tenetur officiis facilis deleniti?</div>
  <div>Est vitae vero culpa corporis ex ipsa, atque, illum quas illo quibusdam cum beatae magni eum quidem magnam iste laboriosam distinctio sequi temporibus tenetur. Non eum nesciunt excepturi, eaque libero!</div>
  <div>Quibusdam accusantium nemo minus praesentium eligendi quis, placeat quo. Ab eum fugit nesciunt labore qui eius iure ex. Ab excepturi labore distinctio delectus ullam vitae architecto unde culpa repellat ipsum?</div>
  <div>Vero dolores aspernatur repudiandae iure consequatur laudantium sapiente impedit quas at facilis illum modi similique quidem asperiores sint vitae voluptate consequuntur consectetur tenetur, voluptates eligendi numquam! Magni nam, voluptate voluptatibus.</div>
  <div>Atque ducimus, repellat, nulla quae magnam iure eius ad quo ab at, quod dolor. Enim at quisquam, itaque aspernatur quam adipisci iusto consectetur consequuntur ducimus! Quaerat aspernatur ipsam earum vero.</div>
  <div>Quibusdam sunt maxime magni temporibus, velit fugit ducimus sed eum rem doloremque voluptatem reprehenderit dignissimos, aut inventore vero. Iste ipsam at in velit, doloribus, a. Distinctio accusamus, veniam ratione voluptatibus.</div>
  <div>Asperiores temporibus quae aspernatur quos. Enim doloribus nesciunt nihil dignissimos consequuntur officiis. Quia possimus molestias iusto dicta atque, modi officia, assumenda beatae quod, minus repudiandae? Molestias nihil deleniti, aut asperiores?</div>
  <div>A, tempore dignissimos eaque laudantium asperiores explicabo perferendis. Accusantium necessitatibus beatae, laboriosam fugit dolor tempora! Totam quod doloribus porro ad beatae quae pariatur perspiciatis, esse nihil iste tenetur quidem voluptatum?</div>
</header>
<div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos ratione odit, laboriosam delectus maxime quod quisquam ipsum iste sit impedit excepturi consequatur eaque eos vel molestias tempore atque commodi, voluptate.</div>
  <div>Similique consectetur ducimus quo tempora. Ad dolorum molestias nostrum, aspernatur reiciendis a provident sed consequatur quod ullam vero fuga quia ratione quam eligendi magnam debitis consequuntur eos quae, esse odio.</div>
  <div>Magnam ad tempora animi sint officiis iure quibusdam optio ullam libero cumque vitae aperiam dolores molestias architecto temporibus dolor mollitia sunt consequuntur eveniet molestiae, esse sed! Sapiente, error vero aperiam.</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias, veritatis optio suscipit at odio enim, velit dolores quaerat placeat incidunt excepturi, nisi veniam, recusandae nobis tempore? Ab aliquam enim nobis.</div>
  <div>Sequi magni, veniam omnis, soluta facere saepe deserunt harum a quasi tenetur quibusdam! At doloribus inventore molestiae debitis alias ipsum commodi, natus explicabo accusantium a non, dicta blanditiis necessitatibus hic!</div>
  <div>Quos nemo praesentium expedita veritatis. Repellendus quod accusantium autem, odio perspiciatis. Cum sit, unde velit recusandae in tenetur, tempora eveniet sapiente molestias. Dolores amet, fugiat debitis perferendis, mollitia deleniti corporis!</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum tempore in sed consequuntur non facere rerum aliquid, modi voluptas explicabo. Accusamus quibusdam rem doloremque, sed rerum unde repudiandae blanditiis et.</div>
  <div>Ipsa dolore natus accusamus aperiam consequuntur tempora ut repellat ullam esse, ea reiciendis magnam cupiditate nobis labore cum nostrum voluptatibus possimus soluta. Magnam quisquam iste necessitatibus cum soluta cupiditate reiciendis.</div>
  <div>Dolor, labore esse dicta quibusdam hic totam, ipsum obcaecati voluptate quaerat blanditiis ab aliquid cumque quia veritatis voluptatum rerum consequuntur quisquam, vero maxime nobis repellendus architecto minus aspernatur sapiente. Eos!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Хотя наверное нельзя.

Comment: @D.Che, что нельзя?

Comment: спасибо говорить здесь.Правила суровые какие-то

Comment: @D.Che, :-D один раз можно, нельзя когда уже сказали двадцать раз под одним ответом например :-) то есть от них никакой пользы нет.

Comment: ,извините за наглость , конечно) Но можно с вами будет как-то связываться , чтобы какие-нибудь не сложные вопросы узнавать по  JS?

Comment: @D.Che, можете так же вопросы задавать, как и этот. А так же можно в чат заходить: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Comment: @D.Che, ну и всегда можно в комментариях под ответом писать, тогда мне уведомления приходят